# About reducible matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm doing a work about Perron-Frobenius theorem, and I'm trying to give a proof of it. I'm stuck, because I found that an irreducible matrix can't have a row or a column of zeros. I understand that this is a property that primitive matrix have, but why an irreducible matrix verify this too?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a characterization of irreducible matrices: $A$ is irreducible if, and only if, it is the adjacency matrix of a strongly connected graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is reducible if there is a permutation matrix $P$ such that
$$\tag{1}
P^TAP=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $A$ would have a zero row, then it could be permuted to
$$
P^TAP=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 0 & 0_{1\times 1}\end{bmatrix},
$$
by some $P$, which is (1) with $A_{22}=0$. Similarly, if $A$ has a zero column, it can be permuted to
$$
P^TAP=\begin{bmatrix}0_{1\times 1} & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22}\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is (1) with $A_{11}=0$.

Hence, if $A$ has a zero row/column, it is reducible. Reversing this implication shows that an irreducible matrix cannot have a zero row and/or column.